# Kohana: How do I set up a third party app

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I have a small app that has its own classes and view files that I want to add to my kohana site.  I will call this app my sub_app.  So if I put sub_app in the kohana app root, I can access this app at www.kohanaapp.com/sub_app/.

Currently, I can't use any classes that are defined in my Kohana app when within my sub_app.  Is there a way I can load all of the classes in my index.php for my sub_app.

Also, in codeigniter, there is a third_party packages thing that does what I want.  Is there anything similar in kohana?

Answer (score 1):

Kohana uses `Kohana::find_file()` to load external library code. Here's an example:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/autoloading#include-zends-autoloader-in-your-bootstrap

Typically, you would place third-party libraries in `application/vendor`, accessing them like this within your controller method:

```
// Load the library's feed.class.php file
require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'rss-php/feed.class');
```

I've never attempted to load code from a directory above the application root, however, and I'm not sure that Kohana will find your class files.

You could try to load them with `Kohana::find_file()`, like so:

```
// Load classes/autoload.php from two directories above application
require Kohana::find_file('../../classes', 'autoload');
```

Or simply require based on `DOCROOT`, which is the base of your `sub_app`:

```
require DOCROOT
      . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
      . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
      . 'autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your `sub_app` class files to `APPPATH . 'classes'` (`/application/classes/`) folder and modify their names due to [Kohana Cascading Filesystem](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files) principles.

For example:

```
/application/
 classes/
  sub/
   class.php
```

`class.php` file would be:

```
class Sub_Class {}
```

Then you can use your `sub_app` classes like `$class = new Sub_Class;`

Answer (score 1):

You can define autoloader for `sub_app` and register in somewhere in `bootstrap.php`:

```
// find autoloader function/class in vendor/sub_app/ directory
require_once Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'sub_app/autoloader');

// register autoloader::load() function as autoloader
spl_autoload_register(array('autoloader', 'load'));
```

Note that you must manually include your classes in that autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

Well sounds like you just need to add another "application" folder into the directory structure. Consider the following suggestion:

kohana 
  --application // for www.kohanaapp.com 
     --bootstrap.php 
     --.htaccess

--subapp // for www.kohanaapp.com/sub_app/ 
    ---bootstrap.php ->  
            here edit the

```
 Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/kohanaapp/sub_app',
    'index_file' => FALSE
 ));

---.htaccess
      here edit:
      RewriteRule .* /kohanaapp/subapp/index.php/$0 [PT]
```